# Facebook iFrame JavaScript SDK - Without OAuth

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to display an iFrame modal dialog on a website so users can post to their Facebook wall.

I keep getting the dreaded 102 error: `Session key invalid or no longer valid... Iframe dialogs must be called with a session key`.

I've found various [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9536542/723007) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/a/837573/723007) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10775499/723007) for the same issue, but the solutions all involve obtaining an access key for the user or using a server-side SDK.

I have no need to authenticate the user or access any of their info. And I am using the JavaScript SDK (nothing server-side).

I just want to open the modal and let them post. It's just a website, not an app.

Is it possible to modify my code to allow posting via iFrame without having to authenticate the user on my site, request permissions from the user, or call anything server-side?

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {

  FB.init({
    appId: '12345',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: false
  });

  FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Post Name',
    link: 'http://www.foosite.com',
    picture: 'http://foosite.com/img/img.jpg',
    caption: 'Caption for Picture',
    description: 'Description for Post',
    display: 'iframe'
  },
    function(response) {
      if (response && response.post_id) {
        console.log('Post was published');
      } else {
        console.log('Post was not published');
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not allow using iframes for dialog unless the user has already authorized the app. This is to reduce the risk of click-jacking.

Normally you should not specify the display parameter, and the JS SDK will select the most appropriate one based on whether the app is authorized or not.